# Routing data to API then to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

This is a general question about tracking data on Google Analytics. My firm has a larger than average number of individuals opting-out of Google Analytics for privacy reasons -- that's fine -- but we'd still like to capture that a purchase was made by someone and store that in Google Analytics Goals (currently these individuals are not even showing up on GA pageviews or on our quoting page).

The question is, when the individual uses the click event to make a purchase could I route that individual's data to another page (or API call?) and then send it on to Google Analytics so that the record of a purchase is captured? Has anyone ever done something like this?

I want to respect individual's rights to privacy but I'd still like to know that we are capturing 100% of purchases made in Google Analytics Goals.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [TOS state specifically](https://www.google.de/analytics/terms/us.html) in §7:

> You must not circumvent any privacy features (e.g., an opt-out) that
>   are part of the Service.

you are on very thin ice here (you can try to argue with Google that this is not circumventing, but you shouldn't hold your breath and they will terminate your account if you violate the TOS).

Else: sure, use the [hit builder to construct a tracking url](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=555&ec=purchase&ea=completed&dp=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fconfirmation%2Fpage) for the measurement protocol:

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-123456-1&cid=555&ec=purchase&ea=completed&dp=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fconfirmation%2Fpage
```

This will register an event with the event category (ec) "purchase", the event action "completed" for the document path (dp) "/path/to/confirmation/page" for an generic client id. Set this as image source for a tracking pixeln that is fired only for opt-out users.